# How would one modify the filtering Gutenberg applies to pasted content?

Tags: filters, block-editor

**Note:** I'm adding information I discover that seems to be leading to a resolution in the note.

## The Problem:

**When pasting content from a source external to Gutenberg into Gutenberg some HTML/CSS formatting is lost.[1]** While Gutenberg retains most HTML (semantic) elements it drops CSS (styling/non-semantic) elements. This means that properties such as font size, text alignment, text color, etc. are all removed during the paste event.

## Not the Problem:

We could discuss the plugins, custom HTML blocks, etc. (e.g., Wordable, JetPack) available for converting external content sources (e.g., Google Docs) to WP friendly content but this question is decidedly not about those solutions. Instead, **this question is exclusively focused on how to programmatically alter** Gutenberg's paste handling behavior.

## Seeing the Problem in Action

This problem occurs in many circumstances. For example, try pasting the following block of HTML into the paragraph block in Gutenberg:

`<p style="color:red">Hello WordPress StackExchange!</p>`

Then view the HTML for that paragraph block and you'll see:

`<p>Hello WordPress StackExchange!</p>`

The `style="color:red"` has been stripped out.

## Looking at the Paragraph Block

One of the blocks that suffers from this stripping is the paragraph block (`/gutenberg/packages/block-library/src/paragraph`). This block[2] uses the `RichText` component (`/gutenberg/packages/block-editor/rich-text`) to implement its rich text editing functionality.

## Looking at the RichText Component

In `/rich-text/index.js` we find the `onPaste` method which the paragraph block inherits. This function in turn calls the `pasteHandler` function (`/gutenberg/packages/blocks/src/api/raw-handling/paste-handler.js`).

## Looking at the Paste Handler

The `pasteHandler` function "Converts an HTML string to known blocks. Strips everything else." according to the JSDoc.

This function takes five parameters:

- `HTML` = The source content to convert if in HTML format
- `plainText` = The source content to convert if in text format
- `mode` = Whether to paste the content in as blocks or inline content in existing block.
- `tagName` = What tag we are inserting the content into.
- `canUserUseUnfilteredHTML` = Initially I thought this determined whether one could use any HTML/CSS one desired but it appears to be more limited, AFAIK it only determines whether the `iframeRemover` function is run against the pasted content, which is only tangentially relevant.

We can see that `pasteHandler` is imported (`index.js`):

```js
import { 
  pasteHandler, 
  children as childrenSource, 
  getBlockTransforms, 
  findTransform, 
  isUnmodifiedDefaultBlock
 } from '@wordpress/blocks';
```

`pasteHandler` is then called from `onPaste`:

```js
onPaste( { value, onChange, html, plainText, files } ) {

...

if ( files && files.length && ! html ) {
  const content = pasteHandler( {
    HTML: filePasteHandler( files),
    mode: 'BLOCKS',
    tagName,
} );

...

const content = pasteHandler ( {
  HTML: html,
  plainText,
  mode,
  tagName,
  canUserUseUnfilteredHTML,
} );

...

}
```

We are interested for our purposes only in a portion of the pasteHandler function:

```js
const rawTransforms = getRawTransformations();
const phrasingContentSchema = getPhrasingContentSchema( 'paste' );
const blockContentSchema = getBlockContentSchema( rawTransforms, phrasingContentSchema, true );

const blocks = compact( flatMap( pieces, ( piece ) => {
    ...

    if ( ! canUserUseUnfilteredHTML ) {
        // Should run before `figureContentReducer`.
        filters.unshift( iframeRemover );
    }

    const schema = {
        ...blockContentSchema,
        // Keep top-level phrasing content, normalised by `normaliseBlocks`.
        ...phrasingContentSchema,
    };

    piece = deepFilterHTML( piece, filters, blockContentSchema );
    piece = removeInvalidHTML( piece, schema );
    piece = normaliseBlocks( piece );
    piece = deepFilterHTML( piece, [
        htmlFormattingRemover,
        brRemover,
        emptyParagraphRemover,
    ], blockContentSchema );

    ...

    return htmlToBlocks( { html: piece, rawTransforms } );
} ) );
```

Even here, most of what occurs is not relevant to our current issue. We don't care, for example, about Google Doc UIDs being removed or Word lists being converted.

Instead we are interested in:

- `rawTransforms` - contains the results of a call to `getRawTransformations`, also defined in `paste-handler.js`.

  - I don't think this code is involved, but maybe someone can help me understand what it does? :)
- `phrasingContentSchema` - contains the results of calling `getPhrasingContentSchema`, defined in `phrasing-content.js`.

  - This appears to remove a few invisible attributes (u, abbr, data, etc.) which could be part of this problem but the more likely issues folks will run into are with the CSS styles, not these attributes.
- `blockContentSchema` - contains the results of a call to `getBlockContentSchema`, defined in `utils.js`.

  - Again,not entirely sure I understadn what it does, but I don't think it is involved.
- `phrasingContentReducer` - one of the filters, defined in `phrasing-content-reducer.js`.

  - I'm unsure but I suspect this snippet may be involved:

```js
if ( node.nodeName === 'SPAN' && node.style ) {
  const {
    fontWeight,
    fontStyle,
    textDecorationLine,
    textDecoration,
    verticalAlign,
  } = node.style;
```

- `deepFilterHTML` - defined in `utils.js`, essentially a wrapper for `deepFilterNodeList`, also found in `utils.js`.

  - Again, not sure I understand this segment of code, could be involved.
- `removeInvalidHTML` - defined in `utils.js`, essentially a wrapper for `cleanNodeList`, also found in `utils.js`.

  - Believe this is involved, `cleanNodeList` JSDoc states, "Given a schema, unwraps or removes nodes, attributes and classes on a node".

You'll notice several functions that did not make the list - after reviewing their code, I don't believe they are involved in the current problem (e.g., `normaliseBlocks`, `brRemover`, `emptyParagraphRemover`, etc).

## The Conclusion

I just rewrote most of this question, I'll try to refine a bit later and share more on what specific snippets of code that I did not understand does when I have a chance to look at it. Hoping that this may be helpful to others / someone may be able to explain to me what I am missing...or I can keep slogging away. :)

[1] Technically, this isn't always true. Some blocks may accept most/all content pasted into them - for example the HTML block. But the retaining of pasted content is an exception to and not the rule.

[2] You can find the reference in `/paragraph/edit.js` in the `ParagraphBlock` function.

Comment: Is it possible that data isn't in the clipboard? If you know a way to keep that data given an appropriate mechanism, I think the GB team would quite like the contribution so all users can benefit, I'd be curious how myself

Comment: @TomJNowell - I used a small app called ClipView to see the raw content of my clipboard and the CSS is present. Also, based on some conversations in Github issues it seems the decision was made to strip the CSS and retain only semantic (HTML) content.

Comment: Did you take a look at [this part](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-blocks/#pasteHandler) of the docs already?

Comment: Hi Cas, I did. The docs are pretty sparse.

Answer (score 1):

In my blocks.js , located in wp-includes/js/dist/ I find the `RemoveInvalidHTML` function, which seems to responsible for removing styles from pasted HTML.

```js
/**
 * Given a schema, unwraps or removes nodes, attributes and classes on HTML.
 *
 * @param {string} HTML   The HTML to clean up.
 * @param {Object} schema Schema for the HTML.
 * @param {Object} inline Whether to clean for inline mode.
 *
 * @return {string} The cleaned up HTML.
 */


function removeInvalidHTML(HTML, schema, inline) {
  var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
  doc.body.innerHTML = HTML;
  cleanNodeList(doc.body.childNodes, doc, schema, inline);
  return doc.body.innerHTML;
}
```

As you can see, this returns **only** the innerHTML . Modifying (creating a customized version of) this function would likely solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played too much with Gutenberg, but I'll most likely need to solve something similar in the future,

What i'd do, is just edit the function directly, for a quick debug.

```
const rawTransforms = getRawTransformations();
const phrasingContentSchema = getPhrasingContentSchema( 'paste' );
const blockContentSchema = getBlockContentSchema( rawTransforms, phrasingContentSchema, true );

const blocks = compact( flatMap( pieces, ( piece ) => {
    ...
    // console.log( "Piece - deepFilterHTML" )
    // console.log( piece );

    piece = deepFilterHTML( piece, filters, blockContentSchema );

    // console.log( "Piece - removeInvalidHTML" )
    // console.log( piece );

    piece = removeInvalidHTML( piece, schema );

    // console.log( "Piece - normaliseBlocks" )
    // console.log( piece );

    piece = normaliseBlocks( piece );

    // console.log( "Piece - deepFilterHTML" )
    // console.log( piece );

    piece = deepFilterHTML( piece, [
        htmlFormattingRemover,
        brRemover,
        emptyParagraphRemover,
    ], blockContentSchema );

    ...

    return htmlToBlocks( { html: piece, rawTransforms } );
} ) );
```

I'm pretty sure the spot that acts different for the doc paste vs HTML is the "cleanNodeList" function, that has 4 arguments : nodeList, doc, schema, inline

The **schema** parameter is "An array of functions that can mutate with the provided node."

I'd figure out what this outputs for the cases when your html / doc is *filtered* vs *not filtered*

Then I'd figure out how I can change that parameter, because I think when it's "filtered" it goes on the default.

This is how slim the code that runs on the default is :

```
  cleanNodeList(node.childNodes, doc, schema, inline); // For inline mode, insert a line break when unwrapping nodes that
  // are not phrasing content.

  if (inline && !isPhrasingContent(node) && node.nextElementSibling) {
    Object(external_this_wp_dom_["insertAfter"])(doc.createElement('br'), node);
  }

  Object(external_this_wp_dom_["unwrap"])(node);
```

**external_this_wp_dom_["unwrap"]** most likely relies on phrasing_content_phrasingContentSchema when running the default filtering, and from the looks of it `<span>` tags aren't defined at all.

```
var phrasing_content_phrasingContentSchema = {
  strong: {},
  em: {},
  s: {},
  del: {},
  ins: {},
  a: {
    attributes: ['href', 'target', 'rel']
  },
  code: {},
  abbr: {
    attributes: ['title']
  },
  sub: {},
  sup: {},
  br: {},
  '#text': {}
}
```

Hopefully this helps.